# Android - how to escape @ symbol in setText() method

Tags: android

I am trying to set text for an `EditText` field.

```
String someText = "test@test.com"
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.someEditTextField);
et.setText(someText);
```

I have tried `someText.replace("@", "\' @");` but it does not work.

I get the following exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with escaping an `@` sign. As the error points out to you, `et` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As @CommonsWare states, this is your problem:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.someEditTextField);
```

your object `et` is null. You probably need to inflate/reference the layout it is in first.

An "@" is acceptable.